# Security of connection from insecure site to a secure site

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, http, stripe-payments

If I make an AJAX POST request from an insecure (http) site to a secure (https), is that connection still secure due to it originating from a non-secure site? If my website sends a request to `https://www.google.com`, is that any less secure than me typing that into my browser?

I'm curious about payment integration, such as with stripe. For example, if I own htttp://www.example.com and someone purchases something through stripe on my site. This was in stripe's API (albeit not AJAX like the title of this thread, but that wouldn't make a difference, would it?).

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-image="/square-image.png"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

Could this payment be made (reasonably) safely from my non-http site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the connection to your web site is not secured, an attacker could potentially modify the content of the page (or of any Javascript it includes over HTTP) to replace the Stripe script with a malicious service of their choosing which looks the same, but steals the user's credit card information.

---

Follow-up:

> If my website sends a request to https://www.google.com, is that any less secure than me typing that into my browser?

Yes, it is, because the address being requested may be under the control of an attacker that has modified the contents of the page in transit, and it will not necessarily be apparent to a user if the address has actually been substituted for a different one.

Comment: I think I understand. You're saying the connection to my site is insecure (obviously), but assuming the request to stripe isn't directed elsewhere by an attacker, once that HTTPS connection is made out to stripe, it is secure?

Comment: There is no connection "from your site to the https site" - both requests are made by the user's browser. Besides that, though, you are correct that the issue is in verifying that the request actually goes where it's supposed to. However, there is no way to ensure this is the case without HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry, that was poor wording on my part. I meant from the user's browser which loaded my site. Thank you!